# XAMPP installation on ubuntu trusty inside vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, vagrant

I was trying to learn how to make custom made WordPress themes when I encountered some issues and decided to learn PHP. following [the instructions in the official apachefriends website](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html),  when I tried the command 
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
everything went as expected expect in the last step it suddenly stops. I put a screenshot of my terminal here:

[image]

I do not understand what is the problem. I have tested many other applications on vagrant without any issues. I would appreciate if anybody could help me.

Comment: I assume that you tried to rerun it before you posted?

Comment: no, it just stopped!

Comment: I found the answer, I need to add memory to the vagrant VM. I tried to answer in details below but apparently website has blocked my account for poor answers!

Comment: would it not be better to use sudo apt-get install lamp-server

Comment: I left this post while ago and now I'm not actively working on the same issue anymore. As you may see in the comments the problem was that the guest machine went out of space in the middle of installation. so I don't think using a different installation method helps. unless it really takes less space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all a general tip for using vagrant:
whenever something weird happens and you don't know how to solve it activate the GUI. to do that open the Vagrantfile in the folder where your vagrant VM is. uncomment the lines below:

> config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
>
> vb.gui = true

and add "end" right after.

most of the time there are some messages from VM which are not shown in the ssh or vagrant terminal output.

in this case apparently the system was out of memory. the error shown in virtualbox was:

> Out of memory: Kill process

so I had to add some memory to the vagrant VM. to do so you need to open the Vagrantfile again

and uncomment the line

> vb.memory = "1024"

and add some code on top and an "end" after.